# ClassLoader loading class from jar and directory difference

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classloader

I'm trying to load classes from tree structure similar to JavaEE web application. So I have directory which contains compiled classes (/classes) and sibling directory with libraries (/lib). In classes package structure I have compiled class com.test.Test.class with simple logic:

---

```
package com.test;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.test.GameObjectState;

public class Test extends Thread {  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.put("state", GameObjectState.REMOVED);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }
}
```

And here's my main:

---

```
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(repository);
Class<?> testClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.test.Test");
Thread t = (Thread) testClass.newInstance();
t.start();
```

My ClassLoader implementation follows the delegation model. During context init finally JSONObject & JSONException will be scanned and found in lib/java-json.jar (matching corresponding JarEntry binary name inside). When JarEntry found - creates InputStream to load data in buffer to define class.

JSONException loaded successfully while JSONObject failed on ClassFormatError. Magic is that I've extracted JSONObject in /classes directory manually from java-json.jar and no ClassFormatError has been thrown, JSONObject created and output printed successfully. Probably should note that JSONObject has inner/nested classes compiled in library.

And here's my classloader

```
public class WebAppClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    private static final String CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX = ".class";
    private static final String JAR_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jar";
    private static final String CLASS_NOT_FOUND = "Class %s not found";

    private File classesDirectory;
    private Map<String, Class<?>> classes;

    public WebAppClassLoader(File classesDirectory, URL[] urls) {
        super(urls);
        this.classesDirectory = classesDirectory;
        this.classes = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Class<?>>();
    }

    public static WebAppClassLoader newInstance(File classesDirectory, File libDirectory) throws IOException {
        File[] jars = libDirectory.listFiles(new JarFilter());
        Set<URL> jarUrls = new HashSet<URL>();
        for(File jar : jars) {
            jarUrls.add(jar.toURI().toURL());
        }
        return new WebAppClassLoader(classesDirectory, jarUrls.toArray(new URL[jarUrls.size()]));
    }

    protected static class DirectoryFilter implements FileFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.isDirectory();
        }
    }

    protected static class ClassFilter implements FileFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX);
        }
    }

    protected static class JarFilter implements FileFilter {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File pathname) {
            return pathname.getName().endsWith(JAR_FILE_SUFFIX);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> result = null;

        byte[] buffer = null;
        try {
            buffer = scanClasses(classesDirectory, asPathName(name));
            if(buffer == null) {
                buffer = scanLib(asPathName(name).replace('\\', '/'));
            }
            if(buffer != null) {
                result = defineClass(name, buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                classes.put(name, result);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(result == null) {
            String error = String.format(CLASS_NOT_FOUND, name);
            throw new ClassNotFoundException(error);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private byte[] scanClasses(File file, String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] result = null;
        File[] directories = file.listFiles(new DirectoryFilter());
        File[] classes = file.listFiles(new ClassFilter());

        for(File classFile : classes) {
            if(classFile.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(path)) {
                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(classFile);
                input.read(result = new byte[input.available()]);
                input.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        if(result == null) {
            for(File directory : directories) {
                result = scanClasses(directory, path);
                if(result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private byte[] scanLib(String path) throws IOException {
        byte[] result = null;

        for(URL url : getURLs()) urlLoop:{
            File file = new File(url.getFile());
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);
            try {
                Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
                while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                    if(entry.getName().endsWith(path)) {
                        InputStream input = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                        input.read(result = new byte[input.available()]);
                        break urlLoop;
                    }
                }
            }finally {
                jarFile.close();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> result = null;

        if(classes.containsKey(name)) {
            result = classes.get(name);
        }else{
            result = super.loadClass(name);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String asPathName(String binaryName) {
        return binaryName.replace('.', '\\').concat(CLASS_FILE_SUFFIX);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I read this twice and still have no idea what your actual question / problem is?

Comment: You need to show us the source of the classloader.

Comment: @LanceJava JSONException loaded successfully while JSONObject failed on ClassFormatError. Magic is that I've extracted JSONObject in /classes directory manually from java-json.jar and no ClassFormatError has been thrown... So what is difference between class within jar and in common dir? Seems like problem is not in compilation.

Comment: @BadZen provided ClassLoader source code

Comment: What makes you think a single call to read() will always return a full classfile data?   Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[]%29   - you've got to read() in a loop until you have all the data.

Comment: @BadZen It's working now. Thanks a lot for help and good advice. Seems like I need to learn more about IOs.